# Split a string into two using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string COR000001. I want to split it so that I get only the integer 1. If the String is like COR000555 I should get the integer 555.  Thank you...

Comment: so you basically want all integers after 0

Comment: Does your structure contains only COR*****?

Comment: no, there will be other like MCR,TCP,VCF...

Comment: if only 3 letters then you need refp's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method to use is to get rid of the first three characters `"COR"`, `"MCR"`, `"TCP"`, etc.. and then use `parseInt` with the appropriate parameters such as in the below.

```
var str = "COR000555";
var n   = parseInt (str.substr (3), 10); // force parseInt to treat every
                                         // given number as base10 (decimal)

console.log (n);
```

```
555
```

---

If the "key" in the beginning is not always limited to three characters you could use a regular-expression to get all the digits in the end of your string.

.. as in the below;

```
var n = parseInt (str.match (/\d+$/)[0], 10);
```

Comment: what if he has CORE instead of COR

Comment: @AnkitGautam I'm about to write an edit answering just that, hold on.. but according to the post it **seems** as if it's always three characters. but as said, hold on.

Comment: Hey that is exactly what I am looking for. There will be no "CORE" all of the combination will have only 3 letters. Thanks refp :)

Comment: Can you tell me why we use console.log(n) here?

Comment: console.log() shows the result in the browser's console, like google chrome's inspect element or firebug

Comment: @BasimSherif `console.log` is a debug method to print things to the javascript console, it has nothing to do with the solution - I just wanted to show the output and this is usually how you do it

Answer (score 0):

I had just seen some one answer this question and before i could up vote it was deleted, hence posting the solution on his behalf.

```
var str='COR000050ABC';
var variable=parseFloat(/[0-9]+/g.exec(str));
```

though there was a small modification, added parseFloat

Comment: this doesn't follow the description posted by OP, also; why would you use parseFloat when parseInt will be sufficient - and OP requested an integer?